# How to use JQuery-Object in Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, module-pattern

I am using JQuery in a Module Pattern. I have a question about using JQuery Objects.

See the following example:

```
var myFeature = {

   'config' : {
        'container' : $('#myFeature'),

    'init' : function(config) {

        myFeature.config.container.css('display', 'none');

    }
}`
```

Why does the above example not work? What would be best practice when working with Jquery Objects in module pattern?

Comment: Well to start with, you have a syntax error, the above won't parse. You're missing a `}` somewhere (and the where matters slightly).

Comment: Are you trying to pass your object's `config` as an argument to your `init`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that I've added the missing `}` in the right place *(I also added a semicolon at the end, I don't recommend relying on the horror that is Automatic Semicolon Insertion)*:

```
var myFeature = {
    'config' : {
        'container' : $('#myFeature'),
    }
    'init' : function(config) {
        myFeature.config.container.css('display', 'none');
    }
};
```

...then the only reason I can see for why it wouldn't work would be if this code were executed *before* the element existed. So your `container` property ends up referring to a jQuery set with nothing in it, because *as of when that property was initialized*, there was no element with the `id` `"myFeature"`.

The solution would be to initialize the `container` property at a time when you know the element exists, or to not use the `container` property at all since looking up an element by its `id` is *very, very* fast.

If the element is in the main markup of your page, make sure that the `script` tag that contains the code above is *after* that markup. The usual recommendation is to put the `script` tag(s) at the very end of your page, just before the closing `</body>` tag, so that all elements in the page's markup exist as of when the script code runs.

Comment: Thanks you. You were right: the js-script was executed before the element was build. Putting the script at the end of the page solved the problem, but:

Comment: How could be a good practice to organize my code then? I use to write the module patterns in a separate js-file and include it at the top of the page. Should I wrap the file in a document-ready? Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @leo_vincere: There's no need for a `ready` callback if you put the `script` tag at the end.

Answer (score 1):

See changes below:

```
var myFeature = {
    'config' : {
        'container' : $('#myFeature')  // 1: removed comma
    },                                 // 2: added comma and right curly brace
    'init' : function(config) {
        myFeature.config.container.css('display', 'none');
    }
};                                     // 3: added semi-colon
```

1. the extra comma will sometimes cause errors in old versions of IE
2. keys/value pairs are delimited by commas in hashes
3. *need* semi-colon at end of statement.  "need" is used loosely, but it's better safe than sorry